# PHP switch statement inside for loop

Tags: php, for-loop, switch-statement

a have very simple problem 
here is my code:

```
$imax = 3;
$licenses = array('pub1','pub2','pub3');

for ($i=0; $i<=$imax; $i++) {

$pub = $licenses[$i];

switch ($pub){
case 'pub1': $pubtitle = "Pub title 1";
case 'pub2': $pubtitle = "Pub title 2";
case 'pub3': $pubtitle = "Pub title 3";
}

echo $pubtitle;

}
```

output is:

```
Pub title 3
Pub title 3
Pub title 3
```

I trying to put `$pubtitle` to an array, but its not working too :(

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're missing your `break` statement which stops execution of your switch statement. Without it everything "falls through" to the last statement which sets `$pubtitle` to "Pub Title 3";

```
switch ($pub){
   case 'pub1': $pubtitle = "Pub title 1"; break;
   case 'pub2': $pubtitle = "Pub title 2"; break;
   case 'pub3': $pubtitle = "Pub title 3"; break;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to add break; at the end of each case.

```
switch ($pub){
case 'pub1': $pubtitle = "Pub title 1"; break;
case 'pub2': $pubtitle = "Pub title 2"; break;
case 'pub3': $pubtitle = "Pub title 3"; break;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use break and defalut to get perfect result on switch case

```
 switch ($pub){
       case 'pub1': $pubtitle = "Pub title 1"; break;
       case 'pub2': $pubtitle = "Pub title 2"; break;
       case 'pub3': $pubtitle = "Pub title 3"; break;
       default: echo "not in our list";
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a perfect way to do it. Try this out it really hepled me with mine.

```php
for($i = 0; $i < count($array); $i++) {
    switch($data) {
        case 'Now':
            $answer = (stripos($array[$i]['word'], 'Button') !== FALSE) ? 'Yes' : 'No';
            break;
        case 'Next':
            $answer = (stripos($array[$i]['word'], 'Input') !== FALSE) ? 'Yes' : 'No';
            break;
    }
}
```